# Pytorch index with Tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a 2-dimentional tensor `arr` with 0 as all the entries. I have a second tensor `idx`. I want to make all entries in `arr`  with the indices in `idx` into 1.

```
arr = torch.zeros(size = (2,10))
idx = torch.Tensor([
    [0,2],
    [4,5]
])
arr[idx] = 1 #This doesn't  work
print(arr)
```

The output should look like this:

```
tensor([[1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

I had high confidence that I would definitely find someone else ask this in SO, however I couldn't find one.  I hope it isn't duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [scatter()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.scatter_.html#torch.Tensor.scatter_) along `dim=1` or the innermost dimension in this case i.e. `dim=-1`. Note that in place of `src` tensor, I just passed the constant value 1.

```py
In [31]: arr = torch.zeros(size=(2, 10))
 
In [32]: idx = torch.tensor([
     ...:     [0, 2],
     ...:     [4, 5]
     ...:     ])
 
In [33]: torch.scatter(arr, 1, idx, 1)
Out[33]: 
 tensor([[1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])

In [34]: torch.scatter(arr, -1, idx, 1)
Out[34]: 
 tensor([[1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```